# Strong correlation between prior and posterior for a simple bayesian model?

Tags: bayesian, pymc

Consider the following `pymc3` model.

```
from scipy import stats

import pymc3 as pm

p_true = 0.5
N = 15000

data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(p_true, size=N)

with pm.Model() as model:

  p = pm.Uniform('p', lower=0, upper=1)
  obs = pm.Bernoulli('obs', p=p, observed=data)

  step = pm.Metropolis()
  trace = pm.sample(20000, step=step)

print(trace['p', -1000:].mean())
```

I don't understand why the average `p` is different when I increase the upper value of the Uniform `p` prior.

Why the model does not still converge to `0.5` ?

See the following values :

```
**Uniform upper value for prior p**   |   **trace['p', -1000:].mean()**
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1                                     |    0.49
1.1                                   |    0.49
1.999                                 |    0.49
2                                     |    1.00
2.1                                   |    1.05
5                                     |    2.50
10                                    |    5.00
100                                   |    50.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $\mathrm{upper} \geq 2$, PyMC3 chooses a default starting value for $p$ that is so bad that the chain never accepts a proposed step.  To see this, you can compare the traceplots for `upper=1.9`:
[image]

with `upper=2.1`:

[image]

To get reasonable results, you can set a default starting value that is inside the interval $[0,1]$ as follows

```
trace = pm.sample(20000, step=step, start={'p':.1})
```

`PyMC2` would raise an error when a chain started at a point with probability density zero, perhaps `PyMC3` should do so as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Abraham. Things are much more clear now ! I will open an issue in PyMC3.